# How to pass function name to template in extra_context

Tags: django

How do I  pass a function to a template in the extra_context.  Thanks.

Update:
The idea is that in the template I could turn around and pass that function as a parameter to a filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason you can't just pass in the function reference?

```
def my_func():
    # ...

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^foo/$', direct_to_template, {
        'template': 'foo.html', 
        'filter_func': my_func,
    }),
)
```

**Edit**: Rats, that [won't work with generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/generic-views/):

> If a value in the dictionary is callable, the generic view will call it just before rendering the template.

You could probably get around this by sticking your function in a dictionary, though it's not very pretty:

```
def my_func():
    # ...

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^foo/$', direct_to_template, {
        'template': 'foo.html', 
        'filter_funcs': { 'my_func': my_func },
    }),
)
```

I have to say that almost every time I start trying to make generic views do anything slightly out of the ordinary, I tend to waste a fair amount of time before just writing a four-line custom view that does what I need.

Comment: If I try  extra_context={'f': f2} it returns the error, "f2() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)", as if it thought I was invoking it there.

Comment: yes. f2 is a function. I set extra_context ={'f':f2} and it returns that error  message, as if it thought I was trying to invoke f2 instead of reference it.  Are you sure in your example its not just invoking my_func, considering it doesn't take parameters.

Comment: See my edit - apparently generic views call functions in `extra_context` before rendering the template.